# Installing Nvidia Drivers Breaks Computer

Tags: drivers

After I installed the Nvidia drivers my screen resolution dropped and I can't log in. When I try logging in my screen thinks for a bit, turns black with the message /drv/sda2: clean, X/Q files, Y/Z blocks (x, y, q, z are big numbers) and then just returns to the login screen. How do I fix this? I made sure to install the correct drivers, I've tried this three separate times but I keep getting this issue. I have a GTX 690, and I couldn't find any questions with a similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try <kbd>ctrl+alt+f1</kbd> before logging in graphically. It will bring up a terminal. In that terminal after you type your login name and password type `startx` and it should display any errors causing you not to be able to log in. If you are able to log in I would definitely consider opening up synaptic and reinstalling your Nvidia driver. `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (configure pending packages) at the terminal before login might help in this case as well.

Answer (score -2):

- restart your computer
- enter into recovery mode
- terminal will open, enter your credentials
- just run:

  ```
        sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
        sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
        sudo apt-get autoremove
        sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
        echo "nouveau" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
        sudo reboot
  ```

Comment: add this command to step 4: "mount -o rw,remount / " before the apt-get remove command